# Why doesn't model based validation work in ASP.NET MVC 2 with partial views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-2-validation

I'm working with partial views and model based validation.  I'm using System.Data.Componentmodel to add attributes to each relevant field.

When users click on partial views and enter data, no validation occurs--even though I have client side validation enabled.

Why don't the client side validation scripts work?  I've done some googling and found some suggestions--even some scripts that I've tried--but haven't been able to get client side, model based validation to work with a partial view rendered using Ajax.ActionLink().

Answer (score 0):

You do have the ValidationMessageFor elements set-up don't you?

These don't get added by the scaffolding by default and has caught me out a couple of times.